# Custom-макет для actionBar

Tags: android

Для своего actionBar хочу создать макет как показано здесь:
[image]

Здесь показаны 2 активити, для которых хочу сделать одно меню.
Т.е. в нем должно быть кнопка "back", надпись по середине и кнопка "reload"

Собственно вот незаконченный макет:

```
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/custom_menu"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:color="#808080"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
>

 <!-- текст по середине-->
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Type here:">
</TextView>

<item
     android:id="@+id/reload_button"
     android:color="#ffffff"
     android:background="@drawable/custom_item"
     android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate">
</item>
```

У меня несколько вопросов:
1) Нужно ли здесь еще указывать кнопку "back" или можно будет подключить ее через код? Если нужно, то где взять сам значок? Есть ли он в drawable?
2) Правильно ли я тут все делаю? 
3) Было бы неплохо увидеть примеры где-то в сети, как люди делают свой макет под actionBar
4) Можно ли как-то сдвинуть заголовок actionBar в середину? Назначить ему толщину?

Comment: посмотрите [здесь](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#UpNav).

Comment: Про это я знаю, но не то совсем. Мне же попутно нужно и заголовок по центру держать и рамку для "reload button" сделать

Comment: Картинка "угловая скобка - стрелочка" у меня нашлась в стандартных картинках в "@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_light".

Comment: что-то у меня такой нет..

Comment: раз уж Вы делаете кастомный дизайн - нарисуйте и кнопку. Всех то делов.

Answer (score 1):

Для кнопки назад можно установить:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Для своего "макета" надписи используйте:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView(int)

Для своей кнопки в описании меню надо указать:

```
app:actionViewClass="resource.id"
```

Comment: Уже гуглил вчера на эту тему. Так вот, некоторые при кастомизации еще зачем-то добавляют свой стиль для активити: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android 
Зачем? И потом, можно ли сделать кастомную вьюшку для бара явно не указывая в ней кнопку "back", а потом прописать actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);?

Answer (score 0):

Кастомизация как на 1 картинке:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_menu);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY));

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
    textView.setText(R.string.app_name);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_master_view, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**custom_menu.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" 
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

**menu_master_view.xml**:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
    />

</menu>
```